Why can't I import a function from the prime module of num_bigint_dig?
According to this page, there is a function in the prime module of the num_bigint_crate that I would like to import and use, but it seems that I cannot.
I have made a MWE. This is my main.rs:
use num_bigint_dig::prime::probably_prime;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}

And this is my Cargo.toml:
[package]
name = "isprime_bigint"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
num-bigint-dig = "0.8.4"

But when I run cargo build, it complains:
 --> src/main.rs:1:21
  |
1 | use num_bigint_dig::prime::probably_prime;
  |                     ^^^^^ could not find `prime` in `num_bigint_dig`

What am I missing?

It looks like there is a "prime" feature that enables this. Configure your Cargo.toml like so:
num-bigint-dig = { version = "0.8.4", features = ["prime"] }

